# unknown error in array? PHP

Tags: php, arrays

If someone can see a problem with this code I would be glad if you could enlighten me? I have tried `echo var_dump($content_array2);` and its no problem it say the array contains 5 (0-4) strings as it should and it prints the `$values[0]` and `$values[1]` as it should to but still say Undefined offset: 1 at the same row as I echo the values?

```
<?php
    $myFile = 'demo.txt';
    $content = file_get_contents($myFile);
    $content_array2 = explode("\n", $content);      
?>


<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($content_array2); $i++):
       $values = explode(';', $content_array2[$i]);?>
       <li><?php echo $values[0].$values[1]; ?></li>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

for now it is just trash in demo.txt, looks like this:

kgkhjvk;4;mvbjhgv;jkhgiuh;kluhouyghb

jhghjgv;2;j,hgbkjh;k,jhkj;kjhuihb

jhghjgv;2;j,hgbkjh;k,jhkj;kjhuihb

jhghjgv;2;j,hgbkjh;k,jhkj;kjhuihb

jhghjgv;2;j,hgbkjh;k,jhkj;kjhuihb

Comment: can you post a few lines of demo.txt?

Comment: put `var_dump($content_array2);` here

Comment: You are possibly also looking for the `file()` function with _SKIP_EMPTY_LINES. And `str_getcsv` might be helpful as well.

Comment: I just ran this code in my IDE and it worked correctly?

Comment: it doesnt work because i need it to be a string to explode it

Comment: I get this without any errors (<li> list): kgkhjvk4
jhghjgv2
jhghjgv2
jhghjgv2
jhghjgv2

Comment: when the first item is added to the textfile it always appends to the second row, could this be the problem? but shouldnt [0] be undefined aswell then?

Comment: yes it was :) how do I fix that, dont understand why it appends to the second row?

Comment: Not and answer to your question, but I suggest that you eliminate all the switching in and out of php by writing the line `echo '<li>'.$values[0].$values[1].'</li>';` That would allow you to only have the <?php tag at the top and make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your code and tested... Its working now...

The soluton:

```
<?php
$myFile = 'demo.txt';
$content = file_get_contents($myFile);
$content_array2 = explode("\n", $content);      


$values = array(); //says that $values is an array  

for($i = 0; $i < count($content_array2); $i++):

    //values now is an array of array
    $values[$i] = explode(';', $content_array2[$i]);

    //skip the empty line and print $values[$row][$column]
    if($values[$i][0])
        echo "<li>". $values[$i][0]." ".$values[$i][1]." ".$values[$i][2]." ".$values[$i][3]." ".$values[$i][4] ."</li>";

 endfor; 
?>
```

Tested and Working !